# Explanation for behaviour of graph of $y=x^2e^{-x^2}$ (Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution)

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, conic-sections, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics

Consider the function
$$y=x^2e^{-x^2}$$
The graph initially behaves as a parabola then in later part exponential part of it dominates; i.e., the graph looks exponential after maximum of the curve.

Actually this graph is related to Maxwell Boltzmann distribution graph. Please help me so that I can easily remember the property of this graph.

Comment: Please confirm that the function resulting from my edit reflects the intent of your question.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot

Comment: MathJax hint:  for multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces, so e^{-x^2} gives $e^{-x^2}$.  It works for many things, like subscripts and fractions as well.  You can right click on any MathJax and choose Show Math As ->TeX commands to see how it was done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually gave the mathematical explanation.  The graph is below.  Over the range $[-1,1]$ the exponential doesn't change that much-it is $1$ at the center and $\frac 1e \approx 0.3679$ at the ends.  That is less than a factor $3$.  The parabola is $0$ at the middle and $1$ at the ends, an infinite ratio.  It dominates the product over this interval.  As you get outside that interval, the exponential dominates.  From $1$ to $3$ the parabola rises by a factor $9$, but the exponential drops by a factor $2980$, so it dominates.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}\implies f'(x)=2x(1-x^2)e^{-x^2}, f''(x)=2x^2(x^4-5x^2+1)e^{-x^2}.$$
1- Check that $f(x)$ is even and $f(0)=0, f(\pm \infty)=0,. f'(x)=0 \implies x=0, \pm 1, f''(\pm 1)<0, f'(x)$ does not change sign around $x=0$. So min at $x=0$ max at $x=\pm 1, f_{max}=e^{-1}, f_{min}=0.$ All these information helps plotting this function as ny @Ross Millikan in his answer here.

Comment: Thank you sir please anyone can edit the question title and add Maxwell distribution relation so that it helps ones who search for it. I dont have edit privileges